# Where can I find good resources to practice quadric surfaces and conics?

Tags: reference-request, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, book-recommendation, online-resources

I need to brush up my knowledge about quadric surfaces and conics. I find myself understanding things better when I work with problems. Do you know any good textbook or website with problems about these topics? Thanks!

Comment: there is this book that my professor used to follw: Analytical geometry of Quadratic surfaces by Charles smith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [Paul's Online Math Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/QuadricSurfaces.aspx). Here is a set of related [problems](http://dtc.pima.edu/~hacker/vectorcalc/homework-sets/vector-calc-hw3.pdf).